# Yeoman angular generator and requirejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I'm new to Angular and am reading the O'Reilly AngularJS book by Brad Green & Shyam Seshadri   In the book, they suggest using Yeoman to seed your Angular projects, which I've done.

They then go on to suggest integrating Angular with RequireJS. Either I missed something, or there is missing information about how to get Yeoman and RequireJS to work without a lot of manual changes after you generate your project with Yeoman.

Can anyone provide some suggestions about how to get the Yeoman angular generator to work with RequireJS?  I would assume this is pretty common.  Should I just be using another Yeoman generator?

**Edit:**
Wanted to share that since I've asked this question, I've since learned that integrating AngularJS and RequireJS can be quite a pain and that you're better off trying Browserify.  See [this blog post](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/requiring-vs-browerifying-angular/) for more info.

Comment: here's a generator https://npmjs.org/package/generator-arsk

Comment: As a follow up, I think that perhaps this is not just me being confused, there are numerous comments on the amazon reviews of this book that suggest examples are woefully incomplete: http://www.amazon.com/AngularJS-Brad-Green/product-reviews/1449344852/ref=sr_1_2_cm_cr_acr_txt?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1

Comment: Another generator, seems to be active https://github.com/aaronallport/generator-angular-require

Comment: Here's a decent list of generators which may help you (compliments to the above contributors to this comments-thread): https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=generator-angular-require